# Два разных ответа из многомерного массива

Tags: php

Не могу понять, что нужно дописать, **чтобы выводилось 15 и 16, а не 31.**

То есть, чтобы функция суммировала отдельно первый элемент массива и второй.

А у меня функция прибавляет все элементы массива.

```js
function numbers($massive){ 

$result = 0;

foreach($massive as $main){

foreach($main as $child){
$result = $result + $child;
}
}

return $result;
};


$massive = [

[1,2,3,4,5],
[1,2,3,4,6],

];

echo numbers($massive);
```

Comment: Нужно сбрасывать результат в цикле, а не до цикла.

Comment: сделал, но теперь выводится просто 16 а 15 не выводится.
Вот пример: function numbers($massive){ 



foreach($massive as $main){

$result = 0;

foreach($main as $child){

$result = $result + $child;
}
}

return $result;
};


$massive = [

[1,2,3,4,5],
[1,2,3,4,6],

];

echo numbers($massive);

Comment: @Козак Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив новый код, в комментах более одной строчки невозможно читать

Comment: @Козак на тостере же все за вас сделали уже, зачем дублировать?

Comment: Что такое тостер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю просто складывать результаты сложения очередного массива в результирующий, а потом по очереди выводить.

```
function numbers($massive) { 
    $result = array();
    foreach($massive as $main) {
        $cur_mass_res = 0; // переменная для результатов сложения очередного массива
        foreach($main as $child) {
            $cur_mass_res += $child;
        }
        $result[] = $cur_mass_res; // кладем результат в результирующий массив
    }
    return $result; // возвращаем итоговый массив
}


$massive = [ [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,6] ];
$result = numbers($massive);
foreach ($result as $item) {
    echo $item . ' '; // по очереди выводим элементы результирующего массива
}
```